# Adding text, images or listview to a scaffold in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to add an image and text below in paragraphs in a scaffold, along with a listview or something like a table in HTML.

I went through the example of adding the text, but it doesn't contain any padding and it is edge to edge, also I'm not sure how to inserts break to the text.

I have multiple classes with similar structure as it is being called from a navigation bar.

Here is an example of the default class:

```
//Contact Info
class Fourth extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Contact Info"),
      ),
      body: Center( 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I was trying to do with the text, I needed to add a picture followed by a couple of paragraphs of text.

```
class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Supreme Council"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new RichText(
          text: new TextSpan(
            //text: 'Hello ',
            //style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
            children: <TextSpan>[
              new TextSpan(
                text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please specify exactly what you need. Screenshots could also help understanding what you want.

Comment: I need an image on the top, header and paragraph below it. In some cases, I just need a header and some sort of table view underneath it.  The first snippet is the code of the class, which is being used for these screens, and the second snippet is the code which is used in the screenshot here - https://imgur.com/a/S4iPsJF . I have annotated the screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to show such a list. You could wrap a [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) in a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) which would let you scroll. Then just add some [Padding](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html)s. Also keep a look at the [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.io/docs/) and it's [Widget Catalog](https://flutter.io/widgets/):

```
new SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column (
        Padding( // some padding
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 50.0),
            child: Image.asset(...), // add the image source
        ),
        Padding( // some padding
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 50.0),
            child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), // header
        ),
        Padding( // some padding
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, right: 50.0, left: 50.0),
            child: Text("Some more text"), // add text
        ),
    )
)
```

Depending on what exactly you need you could also use the [flutter_html_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view) plugin which supports some basic html tags:

```
import 'package:flutter_html_textview/flutter_html_textview.dart';

String html = '<img src="example.com/yourimage.png"></img><h1>Hello world!</h1><p>Some more text</p>';
new HtmlTextView(data: html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on your RichText, hit Alt+Enter and then select to add Padding. You'll have lots of options, you can see them at the EdgeInsets class page:

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html

You can add line breaks in your text by using \n as in:
"This text will add a line break\nhere."

No, you don't need to add spaces on either side of the \n. The above results in:

This text will add a line break
here.